# Как сохранить готовый файл в другом месте?

Tags: java, android

Есть готовый файл

```
 File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"temp/test.pdf");
```

Надо его прочитать и сохранить по другому пути как-то так:

```
File externalAppDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName());
    if (!externalAppDir.exists()) { externalAppDir.mkdir(); }
    file = new File(externalAppDir , .......);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Но как именно не понимаю

Comment: а почему нельзя скопировать его например или переместить?

Comment: Это и будет копирование (прочитать и сохранить). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот есть например функция для решения вашей проблемы:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
            destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) и [первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867121/how-to-copy-programmatically-a-file-to-another-directory).

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то, что было нужно!